# Rails: attachments.inline[] in mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am looking for displaying company logo in the email when email is sent. I went thought action mailer base and there is attachment inline feature which supports images in mail.

I implemented it in this way:

in user_mailer.rb

```
def welcome_email(user)
@user = user
 @url  = "http://mealnut.com"
  attachments.inline['mealnut.png']

mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Mealnut: New Order #{order.id}")
end
```

in config/application.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "mealnut.com" }
```

in welcome_email.html.web

```
  <div class="logo">
          <%= image_tag attachments['mealnut.png'].url, :alt => 'Mealnut', :class => 'photo' %>
  </div>
```

But it is giving error:

```
undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
```

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

attachments and inline attachments differs only that inline will insert it via base64 but you need to attach a file anyhow to it!

```
  attachments.inline['mealnut.png'] = File.read( Rails.root.join("app/some/path/","mealnut.png") )
```

than you are able to reference it in the view

hope that helped!

Comment: Hey, implemented the solution u suggested. But it is giving error: undefined method `length' for #<File:/var/www/mealnut/app/assets/images/mealnut.png>

Comment: hey cool got image with mail at least :-). but it is not showing in the mail as header. It is showing as attachment.

Comment: inline attachments will be added as seperate mime type encoded with base64. i don't know, what you mean with header, but i suppose you mean attachments but not inline attachments. could you please set this answer to be OK for you

Comment: here u go. Accepted it. by header i mean, image in email, not as attachment.

Comment: thank you very much :-). email are not designed to include attachments inline. when they founded it, it was basically designed for just text messages. afterwards they have added more features (workarounds) so that attachments have become possible, but only via attachments. email clients become more and more intelligent so they are pretty good in interpreting the "workarounds" but here is also a problem. everybody does it differently so you have to be very carefully in testing it. (webmail: gmail, live, yahoo; outlook, mac-mail ...) => especially definition of SPAM!!!